# Depth of document library folders & files

Tags: document-library, file

How can I find out how deep is a document in a document library? Should I simply parse the url of the file and split according to position of slash character? Or is there a better way?

Thanks.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

You can use

```
file = web.GetFile("URL");
```

to get the file object. Then you can loop using ParentFolder until you reach the root 
folder of the document library and count the depth.

- [SPWeb.GetFiler](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/ms476063.aspx)
- [SPFolder](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/ms464259.aspx)

Kind regards
Stefan